# Civisualize for CiviCase not work

Tags: civicase

I have referred to the following:
https://77.68.13.56/blog/civisualize-civicase https://github.com/mountev/civisualize/commit/4810617d23f5a64b95ada1671d4e90b3c164a096

The SQL inside can get the data out, but I can’t see any data on the view. Has anyone tried this method and encountered the same problem, how can I solve it?
[image]

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking - you've linked to two things from 2017 - did it used to work on your site and you upgraded and it's no longer working? Or are you just trying it now, in which case it's entirely possible something from 2017 won't work anymore. What version of civi are you using?